# Sublimetext 3 : Unable to get exit code in external cmd

Tags: cmd, sublimetext3, exit-code

I am running a C code from sublimetext 3 with GCC on Windows 10 and I would like the external cmd to show exit code after running the exe.

Here is my sublime-build file:

```
{
 "shell_cmd" : "gcc -Wall -pedantic $file_name -o ${file_base_name}",
 "working_dir" : "$file_path",
 "variants":
  [
   {
     "name": "Run",
     "shell_cmd": "gcc -Wall -pedantic $file_name -o ${file_base_name} && start cmd /k ${file_path}/${file_base_name}  "
   }
  ]
}
```

I've tried something like this:

```
"shell_cmd": "gcc -Wall -pedantic $file_name -o ${file_base_name} && start cmd /k ${file_path}/${file_base_name} & echo %errorlevel%  "
```

The problem with this one is that the exit code is showing up in the sublimetext shell, always displaying `0`. I guess it's the external cmd exit code.

I would like the `echo %errorlevel%` part to be executed in the new cmd and to display my exe's exit code but I can't figure out how to do it.

**EDIT :**
Here is a screenshot :

[running hello world](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGXLL.png)

My main.exe runs in a new cmd and the echo is done back in sublimetext's own console.

I guess these questions sum it up in a better way :
1- How do I write this script so that cmd can execute a second command ?
2- How do I make it open, run my .exe, and only then display the exit code ?

**EDIT 2 :**

[Here is a new screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hid37.png)

Here you can see my code and the external cmd called by sublimetext's internal cmd with the command from my sublime-build file.
I manually entered `echo %errorlevel%`into this external cmd.
The goal I'm trying to achieve is to modify the command from my sublime-build file, which will be executed from sublimetext's internal cmd, in such a way that the external cmd called runs my code and only then evaluate `echo %errorlevel%`, all of this automatically.

Comment: Try with `call echo %^ErrorLevel%`, or alternatively with `cmd /V /C` and `echo !ErrorLevel!`. Also try to remove `start`, or to use `start "" /WAIT` instead.

Comment: I've tried these, I can't add double quotes in the line, and the other suggestions didn't help. I guess the real questions here are :  
1- How do I write this script so that cmd can execute a second command ?
2- How do I make it open, run my .exe, and only then display the exit code ?

Comment: @double-beep it won't accept this syntax

Comment: @double-beep it kills the interest of having a build configuration, I would have to create a new filename.bat for each new project. The goal here is to automatically build then run my code, which works with my actual build config, but I would like to automatically display the exit code after running my code. 
I manually tried to evaluate `echo %errorlevel%` into cmd after running the code and the value displayed is correct btw. I just need a way to echo automatically after running into the external cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after some additional googling.

I needed to escape the `&`using `^&`

Here is my new sublime-build command:

```
"shell_cmd": "gcc -Wall -pedantic $file_name -o ${file_base_name} && start cmd /V /k ${file_path}/${file_base_name} ^& echo: ^& echo: ^& echo: ^& echo program ended code : !errorlevel! "
```

[image: And a screenshot of the result.]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to achieve this. `errorlevel` is set before you run your command and it want change in the same line. Use `cmd /v` to enable it for cmd:

```bat
"shell_cmd": "gcc -Wall -pedantic $file_name -o ${file_base_name} && start cmd /v /k ${file_path}/${file_base_name} & echo !errorlevel!  "
```

Comment: With this code `echo !errorleve!` is evaluated in sublimetext's console and displays !errorlevel!

Comment: `"shell_cmd"` is the target of this command, it's basically cmd. The thing is that sublimetext doesn't support inputs so I need to run my exe into an external cmd. Hence the `&& start cmd`. The problem is that I don't know how to transmit two commands to this new cmd.